# How to force IE 9 compatbility view to render page in IE9 standards

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, meta-tags, ie-compatibility-mode

I have IE9 browser. My application is rendering in Standard Document Mode which works fine for me. When I select

> Browser mode: IE9 compatibility mode

then my document mode should change automatically  to IE7 Standards.

Is there any **meta tag** that could help me so, whenever I select browser mode, my document mode should be IE9 standards? I have tried this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Summary Dashboardt</title>
</head>
----
---code--
</html>
```

But can't get any success. Is there any meta tag that will be help me?

Comment: As currently written, your post does not contain enough information to determine what you're trying to accomplish, what you're seeing, and the difference between the two.  From a high level, browser mode affects the user-agent string sent to a server; document mode controls the way a page is rendered by the browser.  Your current x-ua-compatible header asks for the highest available doc mode.  If you want different behavior, then you need to use a content value that allows that behavior.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx and the related "When to use" article.

Comment: Hello Lance...Actually i have created one application that is working fine in standard ie9 mode ..but when i switch the compatibility mode then my application does not work proper...that is the only issue in compatibility mode..is there any other meta tag that will help to render my application in compatibility mode

Comment: No, x-ua-compatible is the only tag.  if you want to use it to force what the UI calls compatibility mode, then you want to use `content="IE=EmulateIE7"`.  As discussed in the article, this forces IE to rely on the DOCTYPE to enable IE7 standards mode or IE5 quirks mode.

Comment: Hi @Lance..Thanks a lot for your response..sorry for again asking very silky question.is there any way to force what ever i select in browser mode the document mode should be ie9 standards..i have tried this also :<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">

Comment: It's OK; it's pretty confusing.  Browser mode controls the user agent string used in that session; document mode controls the rendering.  If changing the browser mode is what makes the page work, then you need to find a way to change the page to not use browser detection, as there's no way to change the user agent string of the browser.  (There used to be ways to override it, but I'm fairly certain those were disabled.)

Comment: As an alternative, you might see if running a validator (http://validator.w3.org/) or the compatibility scanner (https://www.modern.ie/en-us/compat-scan) identifies code in the app that should be updated.

Comment: ok..Lance Leonard...Thanks a lot for your quick response..:)